# Preview of Apple system font sizes (e.g. body, callout, caption, etc.)?

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic-type-feature

When choosing a font for `Text`, for example, we can change the font size using:

```
Text("Hello world").font(.system(.body))
```

In this case, body is a `Font.TextStyle` with the following options:

```
        case largeTitle

        case title

        case headline

        case subheadline

        case body

        case callout

        case footnote

        case caption
```

When deciding which font to choose for a component, I'd like to get an idea of what the font looks like. I found [this Apple page](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/) which details the specs for some fonts:

> [image]

However, these don't match up 1:1 with Font.TextStyle, and they don't include a preview. Is there anywhere with a preview of these sizes for some of the more common dynamic type sizes (e.g. xSmall, xxxLarge)?

Answer (score 9):

The only image I've found is [this](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-a-custom-font-with-dynamic-type/):

> [image]

Alternatively, you can also preview this easily in SwiftUI:

```
struct Font_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    let allTextStyles: [(Font.TextStyle, String)] = [
      (.largeTitle, "largeTitle"),
      (.title, "title"),
      (.headline, "headline"),
      (.subheadline, "subheadline"),
      (.body, "body"),
      (.callout, "callout"),
      (.footnote, "footnote"),
      (.caption, "caption"),
    ]

    assert(Set(Font.TextStyle.allCases) == Set(allTextStyles.map { $0.0 }), "Is one of the styles missing?")

    return
      ScrollView {

        VStack {
          VStack {
            Text("Extra small")
            ForEach(Array(allTextStyles.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, textStyle in
              Text(textStyle.1).font(.system(textStyle.0))
            }
          }.environment(\.sizeCategory, .extraSmall)

          Divider()

          VStack {
            Text("Default")
            ForEach(Array(allTextStyles.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, textStyle in
              Text(textStyle.1).font(.system(textStyle.0))
            }
          }

          Divider()

          VStack {
            Text("Extra extra extra large")
            ForEach(Array(allTextStyles.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, textStyle in
              Text(textStyle.1).font(.system(textStyle.0))
            }
          }.environment(\.sizeCategory, .accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

> [image] [image]

Comment: As in 2024 `title2`, `title3`, `caption2`are missing in allTextStyles.